# Click on Modal not passing session variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, e-commerce

Thanks for your time in reading this post.

My requirement is to pass the session variable to `checkout.php` page, which is not happening.

**My code in the first page as follows :**

```
$name='balu';
$_SESSION['ID']=$name;
<div class="size_2-right"><a href="checkout.php" class="item_add item_add1 btn_5" value=""data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" />BUY NOW </a></div>-->
<div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Thank You</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Your Item is added to Cart.What you would like to do next..</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <h4 type="button" class="btn btn-info"><a href="checkout.php">Check Out</a></h4>
        <h4 type="button" class="btn btn-success"><a href="prod.php">Continue Shopping</h4></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

If i disable the link to modal(code line 3) and give direct link to second page, then i can print session variable.

If i go through this modal, its not working.

Please assist.

Thanks

Comment: variable name are case sensitive. So change $_SESSION['ID']=$NAME; to $_SESSION['ID']=$name; because $NAME is not defined

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Its typo error when i pasted here even if i give the case correctly issue is the same.  Its the problem because of the modal i guess.  Please suggest

Comment: Did you try passing the variable through the url? `<a href="checkout.php?name=<?PHP echo $_SESSION['ID']; ?>">`  and retrieve it in checkout.php using `$_GET['name']`  ?

Answer (score 0):

modal window needs a session_start() to access session variables